# Is multicollinearity the issue here?

Tags: regression, least-squares, multicollinearity, descriptive-statistics, r-squared

How is that I get a low $R^2$ if I use $X1$ against $Y$ and $X2$ against $Y$, but a $R^2 =1$ if I use both together?

How does the combination blow out the $R^2$?

Could you please show me that calculation?

The data:

```
Y   12.37   12.66   12.00   11.93   11.06   13.03   13.13   11.44   12.86      10.84    11.20   11.56   10.83   12.63   12.46

X1  2.23    2.57    3.87    3.10    3.39    2.83    3.02    2.14    3.04    3.26    3.39    2.35    2.76    3.90    3.16

X2  9.66    8.94    4.40    6.64    4.91    8.52    8.04    9.05    7.71    5.11    5.05    8.51    6.59    4.90    6.96
```

Answer (score 3):

In multiple regression, you are trying to model observations, $y$ that are supposed to be noisy versions of a prediction, $X\beta$. That is, we should have:
$$y=X\beta+\epsilon$$

In your case, $\epsilon$ is almost zero. That is, both explanatory variables almost perfectly explain your observations. You have:
$$\beta = (-4.515413640943276 \text{ (constant offset)}, \\ 3.097007886142981, \\ 1.031859030944453)$$
This gives you a nearly perfect fit.

[image: Observations are not noisy]

Regarding multicolinearity: By **definition**, multicolinearity occurs when your **predictor** variables, $X1$ and $X2$, are linearly related.

Now, in your case, $X1$ and $X2$ do, in fact, have a high correlation coefficient of about -$0.9$ (I had missed this in a previous edit).

[image: Plots of X2 vs X1]

However, this is not the cause of the $R2$ jump that you observe by including both $X1$ and $X2$.

For, let multicolinearity have been present. Then, we could write for a small error $\eta$:
$$X2 = a + bX1 + \eta$$
In that case, we would be able to write, for each data point $i$:
$$y^{(i)} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X1^{(i)} + \beta_2 (a + bX1^{(i)} + \eta^{(i)}) + \epsilon^{(i)}$$
$$\Rightarrow y^{(i)} = (\beta_0 + a \beta_2) + X1^{(i)} (\beta_1 + b \beta_2) + \epsilon^{(i)} + \beta_2 \eta^{(i)}$$

Now that we know that $\epsilon^{(i)}$ are nearly zero, then, unless $
\beta_2$ were large, had multicolinearity been an issue we would have seen $R2 = 1$ for even the $Y-X1$ regression. Instead, we get $R2 \approx 0$. This means that while $X1$ and $X2$ together are good predictors, they aren't linearly related enough to be good predictors individually.

Having said that, multicolinearity might play a role in other aspects of your problem, given the $X1-X2$ correlation coefficient of $-0.9$.

Comment: Thanks but as both variables are highly correlated, why do you say there's no collinearity? Why could each variable have so small predictive power alone but perfectly fit together?

Comment: I am having trouble reconciling the 3D plot with the scatterplots.  The former *appears* to show linear relations among all three variables whereas the latter show something entirely different.

Comment: @whuber, the plots are right.

Comment: "both variables are highly correlated": which two do you have in mind? $X1$ and $X2$ are not correlated. The reason I said there is no multi-colinearity is because of the definition of the term: "Multicollinearity exists when two or more of the *predictors* in a regression model are moderately or highly correlated." The 3 variables are related by a linear equation but it doesn't qualify as multicolinearity as per the definition.

Comment: @whuber: the 2D scatters are just projections of the 3D one on each plane of the planes. What I was trying to show in the 3D plot was that all the $(X1, X2, Y)$ scatter points lie in a plane (linearly related), yet pairwise, they are not correlated (esp. the $X2-X1$ plot)

Comment: @Salmonstrikes, the correlation between X1 and X2 is -0.9. That´s what I got using SPSS and R. I think that can be observed from your first 2D scatterplot.

Comment: I had suspected as much, but your graphic makes it impossible to see what's going on.  At least consider describing what these graphics represent, for otherwise readers may misinterpret and misunderstand them.

Comment: @whuber: Thanks again for the feedback. I have revised my answer.